# Why "exhume" but not "exter"?

Tags: etymology

As far as I can find, there's this set of words for burying things and digging them up:

**inhume** and **inter**, both meaning *put into earth*

**disinter** (and apparently **disinhume**) meaning *unput into earth*

**exhume**, meaning *take out of earth*

But **exter** is missing, which I find peculiar. After all, it's all just putting things *in* and taking things *ex* of *terra* or *humus*, so you would expect a full complement, but this does not happen. The same pattern may emerge in other words as well, though none come to mind at the moment. Is there a subtle linguistic reason for which constructions pass into usage, or is it just an accident of history?

Comment: My guess would be to look at the etymology between inter and inhume. *inter* comes from Latin, but more specifically Old French, while *inhume* comes specifically from Latin. This would lend to your "accident of history" idea.

Comment: [Exter does exist](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/66970) according to the OED, though it is marked as ‘rare’.

Comment: This is not English morphology. This is Latin morphology. English borrowed a **lot** of Latin words, but not **all** of them; some got left behind and aren't English words (though some of them might have been, briefly). Terry Pratchett has a lot of fun with this feature of English. In his stories, members of the Assassins' Guild, which is very upper-class, never do anything as gross as _killing_ people -- rather, they _inhume_ them. For a fee, of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just a pitfall of taking the English language from Latin. Many words with prefixes that have opposites (e.g., *in* ↔ *ex*, *pro* ↔ *anti*, *pre* ↔ *post*) did not get their complementary opposite word.

A good example is *disgust*. The prefix *dis*- has several opposites, but the word *disgust* (root *gust*, meaning *taste* or *stomach*) has no complementary opposite using the opposite prefix.

Comment: Agreed, whereas in Spanish for example the words 'gusto' (pleasure) and 'disgusto' (displeasure) both exist and are in common use. https://translate.google.co.uk/#es/en/gusto%0A%0Adisgusto

Answer (score 0):

The opposite of **inter**, when referring to burying a dead body, is **disinter**, which can be interchanged with **exhume**.

Comment: This information is in the question.